# Inserting a row in between consecutive rows based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I am populating a data frame in R with 0s and 1s and, in some cases, I need to insert a row between two consecutive rows as long as a condition is met. The condition would be that if Column C == 1 (first row; i) or Column A == 1 (consecutive row, i + 1), the row to be inserted in between them should have a 1 in Column B and 0s in Columns A and C. This condition should also apply in the opposite way (if Column A == 1 and the consecutive row has Column C == 1)

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
|  |  |  |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |

Considering that my data wrangling skills are not that advanced, I tried with the functions `complete()` and `fill()`, but without further luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did not understand the condition, because first you say OR and after AND, but I created a code that you can use and adapt to the condition you want.

#### Data

```
df <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~Column.A, ~Column.B, ~Column.C,
           1L,        0L,        0L,
           0L,        1L,        0L,
           0L,        0L,        1L,
           0L,        0L,        1L,
           1L,        0L,        0L
    )
```

#### Code

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(aux = row_number()) %>% 
  bind_rows(
    df %>% 
      mutate(aux = row_number() + .5) %>% 
      filter((Column.A == 1 & lead(Column.C) == 1) | (Column.C == 1 & lead(Column.A) == 1)) %>% 
      mutate(Column.B = 1, Column.A = 0, Column.C = 0)
  ) %>% 
  arrange(aux)
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Column.A Column.B Column.C   aux
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
1        1        0        0   1  
2        0        1        0   2  
3        0        0        1   3  
4        0        0        1   4  
5        0        1        0   4.5
6        1        0        0   5
```